# How to define a bijection from $(0,1)$ to $(x, -4x)$ where $x \in \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis

How to define a bijection from $(0,1)$ to $(x, -4x)$ where $x \in \mathbb{R}$? I want to show that $(x, -4x)$ is uncountable. Right now I'm thinking of

$$f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \quad\textrm{where}\  f(a, b) = ((a + x), 4bx)$$

But I am not entirely sure if this is a valid function to define.

Comment: is $x<0$, so $x<-4x$?

Comment: Doesn't make sense if $x\ge 0.$ Restate the problem please.